# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child when assigning variable

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a qr code scanning app.

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

import {
  Button,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { getUniqueId, getManufacturer } from 'react-native-device-info';

import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';
//import Testbox from './src/components/testbox';


export default class ScanScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scan: false,
      ScanResult: false,
      result: null,
      phoneID: getUniqueId(),
      qrbase : '',
    };
    console.log("onInit: ",this.state.qrbase);
  }
  onSuccess = (e) => {
    const check = e.data.substring(0,4);
    console.log(check + " " + e.data + " " + e.result)
    //this.scannedQR = function(){return e.data;};
    this.setState({
      result: e,
      scan: false,
      ScanResult: true,
      //test: '',
      qrbase: 'test',
      dataSource: []
    })
    console.log("onSuccess: ", this.state.qrbase);
    if (check === 'http'){ //place additional checks 
      console.log('Checking' + ' ' + check);
      //return fetch('http://localhost:3000', { //
      return fetch('http://localhost:3000/qrCode/scan/', { //
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          clientId: 'Keith',
          deviceId : this.phoneID,
          qrCode: e.data,
        })

      })

       .then(response =>response.json()).then((json)=>{ this.setState({qrbase: json},()=>{
         console.log('Changed qrbase var')
       });
      })

       //WORKS this.setState({qrbase: json.data.Text}

        .catch(error=>console.log(error))
    }

      //Linking
      //  .openURL(e.data)
      //  .catch(err => console.error('An error occured', err));

    else {
      this.setState({
        result: e,
        scan: false,
        ScanResult: true
    })
    }
  }

  scanAgain = () => {
    this.setState({
        scan: true,
        ScanResult: false
    })
}

  render() {
    //const idPhone = getUniqueId();
    const {scan, ScanResult, result, test, phoneID} = this.state
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Fragment>
          {!ScanResult &&
          <Fragment>  
          <QRCodeScanner
            onRead={this.onSuccess}
            topContent={
            <Text style={styles.centerText}>
               Welcome to <Text style={styles.textBold}>APP</Text> scan a barcode please
            </Text>
            }
            bottomContent={
              //<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonTouchable}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{phoneID}</Text>
              //</TouchableOpacity>
            }
            cameraProps={{ratio: "1:1"}}
          />
         </Fragment>        
        }
        {ScanResult &&
          <Fragment>
          <Text>We scanned the site {result}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.scanAgain} style={styles.buttonTouchable}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Click to scan again </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </Fragment>
        }
        </Fragment>
      </View>

    ); 

  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  centerText: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
    padding: 32,
    color: '#777',
  },
  textBold: {
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#000',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 21,
    color: 'rgb(0,122,255)',
  },
  buttonTouchable: {
    padding: 16,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('default', () => ScanScreen);
```

When the app scans the qr code, I get an error message saying "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child". How do I assign the "json" value to my qrbase variable?
I have tried various options, however they all result in the same error.

I updated this post to include the full code.

Comment: Can you please update question with the complete ScanScreen code along with render method as well?

Also, why you are using `return`, you never use return in react, instead you just update the state of the component and it gets re-render once state updated.

Comment: Hey, I updated my original question, it should include everything now